# Enabling popup windows in Chrome by Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My apologies in advance if my question sounds primary, I am very new at QA and Selenium.

I am using Java and Selenium to write a test, at one of my test's step when I click on a button it is supposed to open another window but Chrome blocks the popup window, can I enable popup by Selenium?

Comment: Are you running this on your own chrome profile? Are you able to disable them by following these instructions: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95472?hl=en ?

Comment: I cannot do it manually, it should be handled from inside my code

Comment: I've written this code, but I'm not really sure if it works. But you could give it a try. http://pastebin.com/5mqr9AX1

Comment: Do let me know if there is any error or if it works.

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Comment: @JRodDynamite Woooow it worked like a charm :), please post it as an answer, and let me know how did you write that code, I mean how should I do that by my self. regardless, THNAKS alot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you need to initialize the `ChromeDriver` with a customized configuration which will disable the flag to block popups. From this [site](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#disable-popup-blocking), the command line switch for it is `disable-popup-blocking`. So, using [`ChromeOptions`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html) and [`DesiredCapabilities`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/DesiredCapabilities.html), you add the desired config using the [`DesiredCapabilities.setCapability()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/DesiredCapabilities.html#setCapability-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) function.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("test-type");
options.addArguments("disable-popup-blocking");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

**EDIT:** Just found the same solution on this [site](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/java#enable-disable-popups).

Comment: I just tried this code in my personal laptop (not work) and found this doesnt control "Popups" anymore. Its always "Blocked" irrespective of line > options.addArguments("disable-popup-blocking"); I am using Chrome V65.0

Comment: @BhuvaneshMani - Can you manually check from the settings if the config has been set once you initialized the ChromeDriver?

Comment: I have `In order to provide you with better service, we use cookies on our pages. By using this site, you agree to our Cookies Policy.` slidding popup while launching my site but unable to disabled that while launching using chromedriver.

Answer (score 3):

There is also another option to enable popup windows. Because sometimes your company may block you from accessing any application in admin mode. If the above method fails to work, you can use the below codes to enable pop ups.

```java
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("chrome://settings/content");
Thread.sleep(4000);
driver.switchTo().frame("settings");
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='radio' and @name='popups']")).click();
Thread.sleep(4000);
driver.findElement(By.id("content-settings-overlay-confirm"));
Thread.sleep(4000);
```

- Use the above code before starting your test.

Comment: Yes, options.addArguments("disable-popup-blocking"); doesn't work for me. Do we have any other alternate options to "Allow" the popups? I am somehow not comfortable to write code to go to chrome://settings/content page to make the popups to "Allowed" It looks vague to me

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still encountering this problem, it's probably because they are on an old version of ChromeDriver. Popup blocking was disabled by default from version 21+

Reference: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1291

Answer (score 0):

For me worked this solution:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```