# Popup blocking for downloading page in selenium webdriver, I'm using chrome for automation

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Guys can any one help me out on this issue:
Popup blocking for downloading page in selenium webdriver, I'm using chrome for automation.
I'm using DesiredCapabilities:
Here is my code:

```
 DesiredCapabilities chromeCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
 chromeCapabilities.setCapability("disable-popup-blocking", true);
 chromeCapabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
 driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeCapabilities);
```

Comment: Hi what you want to do? Please write clearly. I have this situations in my understanding. 1) Block download pop up (auto download to specify folder) 2) Some Ad pop up is display while you download content 3) System display any pop up while you download any content. Which is your scenario ?

Comment: Try `chromeCapabilities.setCapability("enable-download-notification", false);`

Comment: Got solution after updating chrome driver

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enabling popup windows in Chrome by Selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33218794/enabling-popup-windows-in-chrome-by-selenium)

Answer (score 1):

This may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/33220191/6241186 the solution for that is:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
chromeCapabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

Note you need to add the options to the capabilities as shown above, not adding the flag to the capabilities directly.