# Disabling popups using C# in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, popup

I apologize in advance if the following question seems to be very basic, but I am very new to Selenium and I really need help.

So what I am trying to do is, I am trying to open a window popup but Chrome browser is blocking it by its own.

I am used the following code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://path/to/selenium/server"), options.ToCapabilities());
```

But its throwing me an exception saying:

> Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'path'.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33218794/enabling-popup-windows-in-chrome-by-selenium), But didn't  help though gave me a rough idea.

Can someone please help?

(Reference: [Unblocking popup using Selenium using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38702008/unblocking-popup-using-selenium-using-c-sharp/38702141?noredirect=1#comment64782355_38702141))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as below :-

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-popup-blocking");

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
capabilities.SetCapability(ChromeOptions.Capability, options);

IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

**Edited** :- if you want to use `ChromeDriver` instead of `RemoteWebDriver` try as below :

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-popup-blocking");
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\path\chromedriver", options);
```

Hope it works...:)

Comment: Hi Saurabh, thanks for the help, but I am getting an exceptions which says the following:  An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'path'

Comment: @Adrija this occurs due to uri..you need to point URL where your remote webdriver server...if it's in localhost I updated in the answer..try with the updated answer otherwise change to point it to server url

Comment: @Adrija Are you running Remote server on your machine??

Comment: @Adrija you can try using ChromeDriver instead of RemoteWebDriver...try updated answer..

Comment: Hey Saurabh, thanks a lot for your answer, but I dont have a remote webdriver server, I tried your answer a lot of times using different urls, I am actually executing it only.. do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: I tried that, but again it throws exception:An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The chromedriver.exe file does not exist in the current directory or in a directory on the PATH environment variable. The driver can be downloaded at http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html.                           I have already downloaded the package..:(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118842/discussion-between-adrija-and-saurabh-gaur).

Comment: @Adrija then point it with that path where chromedriver.exe exists in your system.. change this line `@"C:\path\chromedriver"` with you current location of ChromeDriver.exe..