# Unable to block unnecessary popups in Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, popup

Please consider the below scenario and help me with your suggestions.

I am unable to get rid of the unwanted pop-ups in Chrome. I don't want these pop-up's to be displayed after opening the application, hence trying to block them by configuring the chrome driver not to allow any pop-ups!

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
@BeforeMethod
    public void setUp()
    {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", path to chromedriver.exe file);

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--disable-notifications","--enable-popup-blocking");

    DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

    driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();        
}

@Test(enabled=true)
    public void monsterTest()
    {
        driver.get("http://www.monsterindia.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='jobuser_wrap']/div[1]/div/div[1]/a[1]")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='username_login']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='username_login']")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='username_login']")).sendKeys(uname);
        //rest of the code to login and proceed with the test
     }
```

But still the pop-up is displayed after running the above script. I even tried to run with the below argument also.

```
 options.addArguments("--disable-notifications","--disable-popup-blocking");
```

To my surprise, in both these conditions the pop-up is displayed irrespective of the argument being passed to it. I even checked the settings manually here in both these runs and didn't find any difference in the settings:

```
Settings--> Privacy--> Content Settings--> Pop_ups
```

And kindly note that the pop-up is not displayed if I manually open the application with pop-up blocker enabled.

I tried to refer the below suggestions also but in vain.

[Reference-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33218794/enabling-popup-windows-in-chrome-by-selenium)

[Reference-2](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/java#enable-disable-popups)

Kindly advise if I am doing it correctly or my understanding in this regard is wrong.

I am using Chrome version - 57.0, Selenium bindings version - 3.0.1, Chromedriver version - 2.28

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure those are pop up ? or is it push notification?

Comment: Can you please provide the screenshots of the popups you want to get rid of?

Comment: Sorry, due to insufficient reputation I can't provide the snapshot here. But the pop-up having this url - http://my.monsterindia.com/sponsered_popup.html

Comment: @4M01 - it is pop-up only.